# Android Image - set to stay on bottom of view

Tags: android

I have an image that sits within a relative view, I'd like to set this so that it aligns with the bottom of the view, at the moment it simply centres itself (see screen grab below). I can achieve this alignment by setting a top margin however that doesn't seem right to me as this could vary depending on the device used. Is there a way to simply achieve this? (current screen grab and code below)

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:background="@color/main_bg_color">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src = "@drawable/feature_compliment"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/exit_btn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:text="@string/home"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:alpha="0.5" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/sign_btn"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:text="@string/sign"
                android:background="@color/primary_button_color"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="15sp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

to

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Answer (score 0):

set  android:layout_height to "wrap_content"

```
  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="0.3"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">
   <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dip"
      android:layout_weight="0.7"
      android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

      <ImageView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:src = "@drawable/sample_background"
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
           />

       <Button
        android:id="@+id/exit_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/home"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:alpha="0.5" />

       <Button
        android:id="@+id/sign_btn"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/signUp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color_white"
        android:textSize="15sp"/>
   </RelativeLayout>
```